# Table I successfully created missing

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I just had an RDS instance spun up to a Postgresql db. The database was created successfully and I am able to connect. Problem is when I run this code:

```
CREATE SCHEMA hollywood;
CREATE TABLE films (title text, release date, awards text[]);
SELECT * FROM hollywood.films;
```

This is the output I get:

```
Schema hollywood created
Table films created
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
SELECT * FROM hollywood.films

ERROR: relation "hollywood.films" does not exist
```

What am I missing here? I added double-quotes around the schema name but to no avail. I opened up the permissions for the user thusly but to no avail (bad, I know)

```
grant all privileges on all tables in schema hollywood to bi;
```

I added the search path before my select statement thusly:

```
SET search_path TO hollywood; select....
```

No change.

Comment: "*I added the search path*"  - you should have done that before creating the table. With the default search path, the table `films` was created in the public schema.

Comment: I just realized that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
CREATE SCHEMA hollywood;
CREATE TABLE hollywood.films (title text, release date, awards text[]);
SELECT * FROM hollywood.films;
```

or

```
CREATE SCHEMA hollywood;
SET search_path TO hollywood;
CREATE TABLE films (title text, release date, awards text[]);
SELECT * FROM films;
```

Comment: I just realized my (very stupid) mistake. Accepted and voted up.